# how to check viewbag in jquery and assign value of viewbag to a textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am tring to push data from viewbag to a textbox in Jquery. Here while i am checking whether viewbag is null or not, it shown error as "Condition compilation is turned off" and other function get inactive .
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Use @ViewBag.Phoneno inside double codes. like this "@ViewBag.Phoneno"
```

Answer (score 0):

It cant be done in JQuery. Viewbag is a server side construct to provide some way to provide Arbitary data, from SERVER TO CLIENT. You can refer to its values in JavaScript or JQuery. But you cant assign values to it using Javascript or JQuery. You need to devise some other way to implement your requirement.

Also, When we use ViewData or ViewBag in javascript or JQuery , its necessarily to be used in the View file only(.cshtml, .spark , or .aspx etc.); Since the when the view is passed to the client side - it is converted to html5. Now while this is carried out , this is the place where the tags `@ViewBag.YourVariable` or `@ViewData["yourVariable"]` is replaced. So this solves the mystery why it can't be done.